# Render error in React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Forgive for the beginner level question - I'm very new to react. I'm using reacts bootstrap and I am trying to render a carousel component. All of the bootstrap components have "ReactDOM.render(component, mountNode);", which If i understand correctly, renders to whatever div has the specified id. However, I'm still not very sure how I should return and render my components. For example, I added a navbar by:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Navbar, MenuItem, NavDropdown, NavItem, Nav} from 'react-bootstrap';

const navbarInstance = (
  <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
    <Navbar.Header>
      <Navbar.Brand>
        <a href="http://localhost:3000/">test app</a>
      </Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle />
    </Navbar.Header>
    <Navbar.Collapse>
      <Nav>
        <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
          <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Action</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Another action</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Something else here</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem divider />
          <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Separated link</MenuItem>
        </NavDropdown>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
  );


ReactDOM.render(navbarInstance, document.getElementById("foo"));
```

This works if I specify a div with id = "foo" in index.html. However when I do the same for carousel instance, it does not work:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Carousel} from 'react-bootstrap';

const carouselInstance = (
  <Carousel>
    <Carousel.Item>
      <img width={900} height={500} alt="900x500" src="/assets/carousel.png"/>
      <Carousel.Caption>
        <h3>First slide label</h3>
        <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
      </Carousel.Caption>
    </Carousel.Item>
    <Carousel.Item>
      <img width={900} height={500} alt="900x500" src="/assets/carousel.png"/>
      <Carousel.Caption>
        <h3>Second slide label</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </Carousel.Caption>
    </Carousel.Item>
    <Carousel.Item>
      <img width={900} height={500} alt="900x500" src="/assets/carousel.png"/>
      <Carousel.Caption>
        <h3>Third slide label</h3>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
      </Carousel.Caption>
    </Carousel.Item>
  </Carousel>
);

ReactDOM.render(carouselInstance, document.getElementById("foo2"));
```

My question is in two parts: why doesn't the same method of putting it into index.html work for the carousel? And is there a better way that I should be rendering these components, perhaps into App.js, because it feels as if I'm breaking react convention.

Comment: did you specified `foo2` id in `index.html` page ?

Comment: Yes I did. However nothing is rendered.

Comment: are you getting any error in console ?

Comment: Nevermind: https://gyazo.com/9f384c2ff907c5aeabbf61dcae741b7b

Comment: Make your components functions, not variables. Here's the documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html